# what are read/write operations involved in main memory, cache and processor?

Tags: computer-architecture

please bear with me, I always get confused with the terminologies used in my computer architecture class.

What are **read** and **write** operations exactly? What are their relationship with processor, main memory, and cache?

I always thought that **load/store** are interchangeable with **read/write**...

What about the **modify** operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read** is the same as **load**, and **write** is the same as **store**. **Modify** is a combination of both.

Comment: thank you, but what do you mean by "combination of both"? So, when you modify, you are reading and writing at the same time?

Comment: Not necessarily at the same time, but possibly as an atomic operation. You first read and then write.

Comment: Instruction fetch may be categorized as a read (since fundamentally it is) or use a separate "fetch" category.